# How does Model.where('false') work? I am not sure, what above query is actually doing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I can see query is running something like:

```
select * from <table_name> where (false);
```

But my question is:

In where (false), what is false? Is this talking about entire record to be false, because there is no sense of any table column here? If yes, then what is meaning of a record, to be false or true?

Does above query consider some column to get data from the table related to Model?

Answer (score 0):

I am taking `Model` as `User`

`User.where(false)` will generate query as `select users.* from users`
So this returns all records OR `LIMIT 11` that is limited records as per default limit.

As mentioned in question `'false'` is a string.
`User.where('false')` will generate query as `select users.* from users where (false)`
So this returns no records as the criteria is not met.

---

Just additional information on what will happen if we use `true` instead of `false`
`User.where(true)` will fail with `ArgumentError (Unsupported argument type: true (TrueClass))`

Using `'true'` as a string.
`User.where('true')` will generate query as `select users.* from users where (true)`
So this returns all records OR `LIMIT 11` that is limited records as per default limit.
It works same as `User.where(false)`

Note: Above results as from Rails 5.2.3 console

Comment: in where (false), what is false or in where (true), what is true? Is this talking about entire record to be true or false, because there is no sense of any table column here? If yes, then what is meaning of a record, to be true or false?

Comment: @MayureshSrivastava Here your main question was ActiveRecord snippet. I have shown the SQL query which is getting generated for it. I'm not SQL expert but what I could tell you is when we use `true`/`false` They are treated on Rails level to decide args. But when we are passing them as string `'true'`/`'false'` then they are added to query. Something similar to when we pass query string like `'id = 1'`.

Comment: *To answer your question: 'which column it considers?'*
Not sure but it may be taking those values as evaluated condition. when `'true'` returns all records else when `'false'` then no records returned. 
It is working something like SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

In a SQL (relational) database, the conditions in the `where` clause are known as "predicates".

They are boolean statements which are evaluated for the relevant tables and column values.

So a row will be returned if the predicate `value > 100` is true, for example, or the statement `value in (select number from other_table)` is true.

It's not uncommon to see queries that contain predicates such as `1 = 0` or `1 = 1` included, which are basically the same as what you're seeing - predictaes that are `false` or `true`.

A predicate like that is a constant regardless of the row values of course, and a clever query optimiser will notice that and for `false` will short-circuit the optimisation to return no rows.

This syntax is probably not going to work in all RDBMSs though, but ActiveRecord might generate different code for a different database.